# Unusual behaviour in UIAnimation of IOS

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation

I am moving a view upward to some offset multiple times. My code is here:

```
for i in 0..<10 {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: TimeInterval(duration), animations: {
        view.frame = CGRect(x: view.frame.origin.x, y: view.frame.origin.y - offset, width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height)
    }) { (boolValue) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                print("loop completed -- \(i)")
            }
    }
}
```

The problem is that "animation completed" is printing after outer loop completes (after 10 times), not just after that particular animation gets completed. 
Means , when below code get executed after 10 times

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: TimeInterval(duration), animations: {
    view.frame = CGRect(x: view.frame.origin.x, y: view.frame.origin.y - offset, width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height)
}) { (boolValue) in
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        print("loop completed -- \(i)")
    }
}
```

then all completion block executes

Comment: I think this is likely a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14670506/8441876

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS - completion block in UIView animateWithDuration gets called too early](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14669601/ios-completion-block-in-uiview-animatewithduration-gets-called-too-early)

Comment: my completion block get called after outer loop get completed

Comment: I think it's a not good idea to do animation using for loop. Can you please explain purpose of animation

Comment: It is bcoz loop is running on main thread and that print statement is in a async block.

Comment: i have to make animation like goo.gl/images/jXy3s3 @HiteshSurani

Comment: @MahendraGP i have replaced code of completion block and still not doing what i want `DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    print("loop completed -- \(i)")
                }`

Comment: Use core animation to achieve this kinda of animations in app.

Comment: @MahendraGP , thanks for your suggestion

Comment: anybody knows any library which helps in  creating goo.gl/images/jXy3s3 like animation